# Why does my Mac Pro running Snow leopard freeze on blue screen on shutdown?

Tags: snow-leopard, error, shutdown

### Symptoms

- Mac Pro freezes on blue screen on shutdown. Restart seems to work quite happily, it's just shutting down that my Mac Pro doesn't want to do.
- The chime has decided to become super quiet of it's own accord.
- Running Disk Utility often tells me that I have

  ```
  Invalid Volume File Count,
  Invalid Volume Directory Count,
  Invalid Volume Block Count.
  ```

  or some such similar on a fairly regular basis.

### Attempts

- I have tried replacing the main system drive in case it was the HD that was the problem. 
  At the same time I installed 12GB of brand new RAM.

  It worked fine for a week and now the problem is back again.
  Nine times out of ten I have to force shut down with the power button or tug the mains cable out of the back.

  This was on both the original HD and the brand new one that I've just installed.

Any ideas?
Any suggestions?

I'm thinking of doing a clean install but I don't want to have to go through the nightmare of finding and running all of the installers again. Would Migration Assistant be the thing to use to help with this?

### System

- 2.66 GHz Quad-Core Intel Xeon running OS X 10.6.8

Comment: Hey @sohosteve, Welcome to the site.  I was going to edit your question to try to make it clearer and improve the formatting, but then I realised I couldn't actually work out what your question really was.  There's a load of possibly irrelevant detail on things you have done, but no detail in the actual question of your actual problem.  Can I get you to think about how best to rephrase the question, starting with a full description of the problem, exactly what happens and when etc.  Include the rest after if it's genuinely useful in assisting any of us to answer.

Comment: Agreed; this question is hard to read as one big paragraph, and the text itself is hard to follow.

Comment: You may have to remove the RAM and see if it improves, or upgrade the software to a newer version of Mac if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the problem persists even after many trails of fixing it on different levels. The title is about the problem and the rest is just details of many possible solution that didn't work.

I'd suggest looking into the system.log file to start with. Specially before the last boot-up and after the last freeze points.

If nothing is a suspect of causing the problem in the system.log, then it might be some third-party extension/daemon that is the cause of the problem.

Comment: I don't understand your confusion! It isn't 'one long paragraph' on my browser. It has three clear faults listed alongside a bullet point.
ismail understood perfectly.
The header was the question! With a further description under Symptoms & possible clues.
In Attempts, I listed all the fixes I've tried that have usually got me out of trouble with Macs in the past having used one almost every day for many hours a day for twelve years solid.
Thanks ismail, I'll try your suggestions as it's still refusing to shut down properly and remains frozen on the Blue Screen with the spinning gear wheel...